# Change Datatables scrollY option runtime

Tags: scroll, datatables, runtime

I have a datatable already initialized, and created, with some option in scrollY constructor object.

At some time I need to override that option runtime, so that next draw() function will take care of new scrollY mode. Is it possible?

DT version: 1.10.10

Comment: Datatables doesn't allow or want you to modify settings after initialization. Your best bet is to alter the height of the `scrollBody` wrapper that Datatable places around your table.

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Comment: If I apply a class to the container, the datatables will override it by applying the style directly, so with maximum precedence. My class does not apply after DT renders. So I need to set directly, after DT does it, the new style attribute, in my case height: auto (I want to prevent y scrolling for a dt that increases its height by showing previously hidden rows)